Hackers try to login knowing admins usernames in self made theme wordpress theme
I've got a site in which I developed a self made theme from scratch and with bootstrap. Everything is working nicely but Wordfence report a lot of login attempt from hackers by using the admins username (I'm not using admin as username and I'm not using user ID 1).
How have they descovered the usernames? How can I block them to know the usernames?
I've read that it should not be a great problem because I've used very strong passwords (source wordfence) but I would feel better to have them not knowing the usernames.
Thanks.

The JSON API will allow for the enumeration of authors (and usernames) for a WordPress site. You can't turn that off.
To protect yourself you should:

Use strong passwords (you're already doing that)
Leverage two-factor authentication (either with the community-developed Two-Factor or using WordFence's own support)
Leverage a plugin like Jetpack that also supports brute force protection

Attackers enumerating users and trying to find a way in will always be a thing you have to face. It's a matter of bolstering the strength of your server to keep the attackers at bay.
You can also use tools like the WPScan scanner to see both if your sites have vulnerabilities and exactly how the attackers are enumerating users.

Thank you very much for your response. Searching on web I've found this code that should prevent enumeration from software:
if (!is_admin()) { // default URL format if (preg_match('/author=([0-9])/i', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) die(); add_filter('redirect_canonical', 'shapeSpace_check_enum', 10, 2); } function shapeSpace_check_enum($redirect, $request) { // permalink URL format if (preg_match('/?author=([0-9])(/*)/i', $request)) die(); else return $redirect; }
You think it can work? In any case thank you very much for your answer.
